# Effect just call one time with two Observables in Rxjs 6

Tags: angular, authentication, rxjs, ngrx, effect

I have 2 functions in login features: get salt then login
But when I dispatch the action Login, it just call 1 time (get salt one time)
getSalt and logIn are Observable here.

Is my effect written correctly? Need some helps, I'm newbie with rxjs, thanks!

My effect

```
  @Effect()
  logIn$: Observable<any> = this.action$
  .pipe(
    ofType<LogIn>(AuthActionTypes.LOGIN),
    map((action: LogIn) => action.payload),
    switchMap(payload => {
      return this.authService.getSalt(payload.username)
      .pipe(
        map(data => {
          return this.authService.logIn(payload, data);
        })
      );
    })
  );
```

My get Salt

```
  public getSalt(username: string): Observable<string> {
    const url = `${host}/customers/${username}/salt`;
    console.log('url salt', url);
    return this._http.get<{ salt: string }>(url)
      .pipe(
        map(res => res.salt)
      );
  }
```

My login

```
  public logIn({username, password}: { username: string, password: string }, salt: string) {
    /../
    return this._http.get(url, {params, headers});
  }
```

Comment: Are you saying the `this.authService.getSalt(payload.username)` is called, then the method `this.authService.logIn(payload, data)` is not? If so, what does your `this.authService.getSalt(payload.username)` look like?

Comment: hi @Viquas, the logIn was called. Assume that, the login return an error.
And I dispatch action Login second time, but it not go to Effect again.
When I remove .pipe(
        map(data => {
          return this.authService.logIn(payload, data);
        })
      ); It can call many times with effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mapping to a `login` Observable so you should use `switchMap` instead of `map`:

```
switchMap(payload => this.authService.getSalt(payload.username).pipe(
  switchMap(data => this.authService.logIn(payload, data))
))
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but the effect just run one time at first. When I dispatch the action second time, the effect doesn't run.

Comment: @ĐìnhLâm Your `logIn` function is likely throwing an error then. You have to add error handling to your `getSalt` and `logIn` functions using the `catchError` operator. What should happen when your `getSalt` or `logIn` requests fail?

Comment: my getSalt is oke, but login return an error from api like u said. 
If logIn return oke, can I dispatch action to effect again with switchMap? or switchMap will auto cancel my api in next call API?

Comment: @ĐìnhLâm Yes you can use `switchMap` if `logIn` doesn't throw an error. `switchMap` will only cancel your request when you dispatch the next action while the previous request hasn't finished yet. Keep in mind that while your `getSalt` function might return ok now it could still throw an error in certain cirumstances, so it's best to add error handling logic with `catchError` to every http request if you want your action stream to continue to work on http errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think because of using [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) as it will cancel the previous emit, you could change it to `concatMap` or `mergeMap`

Also how this works without dispatching an action in the effect? I think this should throw an error, if you dont want to dispatch an action (as return) in the effect, you could do `@Effect({ dispatch: false })`

Comment: hi @sarea, the payload after switchMap is not defined, how can I get data from switchMap and initial payload for login calling

Comment: I removed the tip as I didn't notice the `payload` in the `login` function